# How to link two database tables when no integrity constraints are in place

Tags: sql, oracle, filemaker

I am trying to link two tables that have a matching field, but the values for the fields are not the same format. For example, the matching field name is "Serial ID" and the value in one table may be "134A-AC65" but the value in the other table may be "134A_AC65" or any other combination of characters. The issue is that the database tables weren't setup with any kind of constraints and the data has been inputted manually by end-users operating in the field, so the accuracy of the input is questionable. So far, I've found matching values that exist in both tables, so I know that the tables can be linked, but I need to know if there are other matching values, but may not currently match due to poor data entry. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Values seem to consist of "data" and "separators". The key to success here is knowing what all the separators are.

```
create table table_1 (
  serial_id varchar(15) primary key
);
insert into table_1 values ('134A-AC65');
insert into table_1 values ('232A/AC65');
insert into table_1 values ('333:A:AC65');

create table table_2 (
  serial_id varchar(15) primary key
);
insert into table_2 values ('134A_AC65');
insert into table_2 values ('232A_AC65');
insert into table_2 values ('333|A|AC65');
```

Five different separators, '-', '_', ':', '|', '/'.
I'm just replacing them all with spaces for the purpose of joining.

```
select table_1.serial_id, table_2.serial_id 
from table_1
inner join table_2 
    on translate(table_1.serial_id, '-_:|/', '     ') = translate(table_2.serial_id, '-_:|/', '     ');
```

This is how PostgreSQL performed the joins. (Oracle [translate()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) is similar.)

```
134A-AC65    134A_AC65
232A/AC65    232A_AC65
333:A:AC65   333|A|AC65
```

In general, this is the kind of data error you want to repair, because joins on expressions tend to be slow(ish).  There's more than one way to do that. You can update the values in-place. You can add a column to each table, update that column with the "right" value for serial_id, and join on the new column. (Cleanup tasks are left to the reader.)

Comment: Cleaning up the data is an excellent recommendation. Once the data is cleaned up I suggest you add a CHECK constraint on the fields in question which only allows a limited set of characters in these fields, such as A-Z, 0-9, and "-" or whatever separator is preferred. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `CanonicalID` column to each table.  Then write a query to set the `CanonicalID` from the `SerialID` values in each table.  Once you have all the `CanonicalID` values set, you can perform joins based on those columns.  Like this:

```
create table t1 (
    serialid varchar(50),
    ...other columns...
);

alter table t1
add column canonicalid varchar(50);

update table t1
set canonicalid = upper(replace(serialid, '_', '-'));  
/* This might need to be more complex, depending on the kind of problems
you have in the serialid field */
```

...Do the same things with table `t2`

Now you can join on `t1.canonicalid = t2.canonicalid`